# AWS Lambda timezone is UTC, how to change the timezone globally

Tags: node.js, typescript, aws-lambda, timezone

I'm trying to use date in AWS lambda but it's giving all dates in UTC.
There is a way to convert date in specific timezone but I'm looking for a settings which can be set globally.

Since TZ is reserved AWS Lambda variable so can't mention in the environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by setting the property at the start of the function execution:

`process.env.TZ = 'Asia/Kolkata'`